# carriage return in strip.text 'facet grid'

Tags: string, r, ggplot2, carriage-return, cran

please how to insert a carriage return in strip text (`ggplot` 2.0.9)

I tried :

```
mf_labeller <- function(var, value){
  value <- as.character(value)
    if (var=="Nerves") { 
    value[value=="xv1"] <- c("xv","/r", "1")
    value[value=="xv2"]   <- c("xv","/r", "2")

  }
  return(value)
} 

facet_grid(..., labeller=mf_labeller)
```

It returns

```
Warning in value[value == "xv1"] <- c("xv","/r", "1") : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
Warning in value[value == "xv2"] <- c("xv","/r", "2") : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

and only "xv" "xv" on the figure

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you need to `paste` these, not `c`ombine. Also, `\n` will give you a new line `\r` does not appear to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The labeller is telling you that it expecting a string of length 1, and only returning the first element.

Note that I have replaced `/r` with the new line `\n`

```
mf_labeller <- function(var, value){
  value <- as.character(value)
    if (var=="Nerves") { 
    value[value=="xv1"] <-  paste("xv","\n", "1")
    value[value=="xv2"]   <- paste("xv","\n", "2")

  }
  return(value)
}
```

I think should be possible to do this with a regex / string split approach. This works (but I'm sure there is better)

```
mf_labeller <- function(var, value){
  value <- as.character(value)
  if (var=="Nerves") { 
    unscramble <- unlist(strsplit(split = '',value))
    value <- paste(paste0(unscramble[1:2],collapse=''), '\n', unscramble[3])

  }
  return(value)
}
```

Comment: It worked. I have done 2 mistakes. using "/r" and using c() rather than paste(). thank you very much